# Recover unsaved changes in vim

Tags: vim

I had unsaved changes to the file `foo.txt` in a vim buffer before my computer crashed. Running `vim -r` showed that there are no swap files in the directory containing `foo.txt`.

Is there any way to recover these changes?

Comment: No. If there's no swap file, the data is gone for good.

Comment: Darn, okay. Is there a setting I could turn on to enable automatic writes to a swap file on each change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Darn, okay. Is there a setting I could turn on to enable automatic writes 
to a swap file on each change?
```

read `:h swap`, specially followings:

> Updating the swapfile ~
>
> The swap file is updated after typing 200 characters or when you have
>   not typed anything for four seconds.  This only happens if the buffer
>   was changed, not when you only moved around.  The reason why it is not
>   kept up to date all the time is that this would slow down normal work
>   too much.  You can change the 200 character count with the
>   'updatecount' option.  You can set the time with the 'updatetime'
>   option.  The time is given in milliseconds. After writing to the swap
>   file Vim syncs the file to disk.  This takes some time, especially on
>   busy Unix systems.  If you don't want this you can set the 'swapsync'
>   option to an empty string.  The risk of losing work becomes bigger
>   though.  On some non-Unix systems (MS-DOS, Amiga) the swap file won't
>   be written at all.
>
> If the writing to the swap file is not wanted, it can be switched off
>   by setting the 'updatecount' option to 0.  The same is done when
>   starting Vim with the "-n" option.  Writing can be switched back on by
>   setting the 'updatecount' option to non-zero.  Swap files will be
>   created for all buffers when doing this.  But when setting
>   'updatecount' to zero, the existing swap files will not be removed, it
>   will only affect files that will be opened after this.